# Calling a Script when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, jquery-mobile

In a jquery mobile webpage, I would like to call a script defined within script tags in the HEAD section of the jsp.

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerymobile/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $("#button").click( function()
           {
             alert('button clicked');
           }
        );
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <html:errors/>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme='a'>

      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jquerymobile</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
        <div id="button" data-role="button">Click on button</div>
      </div>

   </div>
</body>
```

When the **Button is clicked**, I want the **alert to be shown**. But nothing happens when the button is clicked.

> Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

**EDIT1:**

The following code **brings up the alert** in **Firefox** & **Opera Desktop Browsers**.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#vbutton").click(function() {
          alert("clicked");
      });
  });
```

```
  <a id="vbutton" data-role="button">Click Button</a>
```

Any reason why the same **does not** work with **Opera Mobile** & **Fennec browsers** - where it shows the **Error Loading Page** dialog??

Comment: Just a guess (hence a comment and not a answer): Mobile browsers may not support onclick events on unfocusable elements such as a div. Have you tried a (real) `<button>` or a link?

Comment: data-role="button" generates a real button that can be clicked.

Comment: Have you **tried** using a `<button>` element or a link? The jQuery Mobile Docs say they can be used, too, and to me it just makes more sense to actually use a `<button>` for a button. (But maybe that's just me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to debug statements like

> debugger;
>
> debug.info(....)

which were understood by Firefox/Firebug, but were **causing problems** in **Fennec & Opera Mobile browsers**.

Comment: good to know, but this answer is rather useless to people. you should have marked the other answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are searching for `$('#button')` before it exists...

Try wrapping your jQuery code in a [`$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) or its shorthand alias [`jQuery(function(){})`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

The other option is to include your initialization of the click event on the button until AFTER the `#button` exists in the DOM.  In other words, you can move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the page and it should work.

Comment: thanks for your response gnarf. I have 2 questions:
1. With $(document).ready(function(){.....}), the alert pops up in Firefox & Opera Desktop Browsers. But Any reason why the same does not work with Opera Mobile & Fennec browsers - where it shows the Error Loading Page dialog?? This is important because I am working on a mobile site (not a desktop one).
2. Where should I move the <script> to? - just before </body> tag?
Thanks.